# Constructing finite state automata corresponding to regular expressions. Are my solutions correct?

Tags: regex, finite-automata

I have drawn my answers in paint, are they correct?

(4c) For the alphabet {0, 1} construct ﬁnite state automata corresponding to each of the following regular expressions:

(i) 0

[image: 4ci]

(ii) 1 | 0

[image: 4cii]

(iii) 0 * (1 | 0)

[image: 4ciii]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first two are correct, although the first one might be able to be written as (depending on your convention)

```
(0) -- 0 --> ((1))
```

The last one is also correct, but can be simplified to (whenever you have `ε` appearing, there is likely to be a way to compress the edges and states together to remove it)

```
  +- 0 -+
  |     |
  v     |
 (0) ---+
 / \ 
1   0
 \ / 
  v
((1))
```

(Excuse my ascii diagrams. I'm using `(..)` for each state, and `((..))` for final states.)

Notice that the `0*` is basically a loop from a state to itself, since after reading a `0` the remaining regex to match is the same (as long as we aren't at the end of a string).